# How does permission cascading from sudoers work?

Tags: shell, permissions, root, sudoers

This might probably be a no brainer for unix guys. Just wanted to ask a simple query.
I had created 3 scripts:

1. `wrapper.sh`
2. `inside1.sh` and
3. `inside2.sh`.

Within wrapper.sh I'm calling the `inside1.sh` and `inside2.sh`. Now I have logged in as user `bob` and in the sudoers file I have given permissions for bob to run the `wrapper.sh` as root.
I have deliberately provided no read or execute access for all the 3 scripts for user `bob`. So 'bob' cannot see the scripts existing. 
Now since I have added `wrapper.sh` in sudoers, I'm able to run the `wrapper.sh` file as root. The id command inside the `wrapper.sh` prints `id=0`.

But when the line calling the `inside1.sh` or `inside2.sh` comes to execute, there is an error saying that `inside1.sh` - not found.

So coming to my query:

If a shell script is set to run as root in sudoers file and if that shell script calls multiple other shell scripts, will the other scripts be executed as `root`? Will the permissions cascade?

Can someone clarify? Thanks for the patience.

Comment: "Not found" indicates a path problem, not a permissions problem.  Shell scripts intended to run as root must always sanitize their environment as their very first action; this also is the right time to set $PATH to exactly what you need it to be to find inside*.sh.

Comment: Thanks zwol. I did check. This was not a path problem.

Comment: A process inherits the credentials of its parent, unless there is an explicit call to one of the `setuid` family of functions (or you call out to something that has the `setuid`/`setgid` bit set).  This has nothing to do with `sudo`.  Based on the error it is more likely a path problem, but if you don't post your code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

The whole path to `inside1.sh` must be open to root, otherwise he won't view the file. To check this, run something like this

```
U_PATH= < path to inside1.sh > 
LIST=` echo ${U_PATH} | sed  "s/\// /g" `
T_PATH=""

for x in $LIST
do
   echo ${x}
   T_PATH=${T_PATH}/${x}
   ls -lsd ${T_PATH}
done
```

and check everything either is owned by root or as privileges > 555.